# Localize Float / Double with Jackson XMLMapper

Tags: xml, kotlin, jackson, jackson-databind

I am currently on the look for a way to localize the decimal separator for a float / decimal when it is serialized to XML with the XMLMapper from com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.

The problem I am facing is the following:
When the XMLMapper serializes a float / decimal, it is currently using the default "." as a decimal separator i.e. "2.00".

However, I want the floats / doubles to have a "," as a separator i.e. "2,00".

I have looked all over the place, but still haven't found a solution.

Is there an elegant way to do this using the XMLMapper? Or does Jackson not a have a feature to do this?

My current configuration for the mapper is:

```
    val xmlMapper = XmlMapper()

    xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
    xmlMapper.propertyNamingStrategy = CustomPropertyNamingStrategy()
    xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true)
    xmlMapper.setDefaultUseWrapper(false)
```

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: You tagged the question with java and kotlin, are you looking for a kotlin solution ?

Comment: Oh... yup I'm looking for a kotlin solution. My bad

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this for a while. It was especially confusing, that `ObjectMapper::setLocale` and `XmlMapper.Builder::defaultLocale` did not help whatsoever.

In the end, I settled for writing a custom serializer/deserializer pair:

```
val doubleModule = SimpleModule("CommaDoubleDeserialization", Version.unknownVersion())
    // note: this is the com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.addSerializer extension function
    // it registers the primitive type AND the wrapper class
    .addSerializer(Double::class, object : JsonSerializer<Double>() {
        override fun serialize(value: Double, generator: JsonGenerator, provider: SerializerProvider) {
            generator.writeRawValue(value.toString().replace('.', ','))
        }
    })
    .addDeserializer(Double::class, object : JsonDeserializer<Double>() {
        override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Double? {
            return parser.valueAsString.trim().replace(',', '.').toDoubleOrNull()
        }
    })
return XmlMapper.xmlBuilder()
    .defaultUseWrapper(false)
    .addModules(doubleModule, kotlinModule())
    .build()
```

This is not the elegant solution I was hoping for, but it gets the job done. If you need to deserialize to `Float` too, you will have to add another serializer and/or deserializer for that to your module.